# How to dim some of the items and keep the others visible in a frame?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I want to do something line this:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item First point, dim this on the next slide.
\item Second point, keep this as is on next slide.
\item Third point, dim this on the next slide.
\item Fourth point, keep this as is on next slide.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

So, I want to show all the items on the first slide and focus on only some of them on the next slide by greying out the rest.

I have seen beamer user guide and looked up internet without any success.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the overlay specification for each `\item<spec>` when you want them to appear, or when they should be transparent:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}% Dim out "inactive" elements
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1,3> First point, dim this on the next slide.     % Slide 1 + 3
    \item<1,4> Second point, keep this as is on next slide. % Slide 1 + 4
    \item<1,2> Third point, dim this on the next slide.     % Slide 1 + 2
    \item<1,5> Fourth point, keep this as is on next slide. % Slide 1 + 5
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```